# Element-plus & server side rendering - wrong hydration for select options (ID_INJECTION_KEY not provided)

Tags: vuejs3, server-side-rendering, element-ui, element-plus

When form contains two el-select compoents, then both are bound to same options on server side rendered page.

Element+ warns about it with

```
ElementPlusError: [IdInjection] Looks like you are using server rendering, you must provide a id provider to ensure the hydration process to be succeed
usage: app.provide(ID_INJECTION_KEY, {
  prefix: number,
  current: number,
})
```

It seems, without id, both selects are indistinguishable when client side performing hydration.
Anyway, selects/inputs seems to be generated without id at all.

Providing following in app create

```
app.provide(ID_INJECTION_KEY, {
   prefix: 100,
   current: 0,
})
```

dismiss warning, but doesn't help with option binding.

How to fix it properly?

Comment: Same issue here. have you found a fix? Thanks

Comment: @HugoH unfortunately not. I just conditionally excluded whole part from server side rendered version as workaround.

Answer (score 4):

[image: 1]

This is the way I fix this bug

```
import { ID_INJECTION_KEY } from "element-plus";
import type { NuxtApp } from "nuxt3/app";
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "nuxt3/app";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp: NuxtApp) => {
  const elementPlusPlugin = {};
  nuxtApp.vueApp.provide(ID_INJECTION_KEY, {
    prefix: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    current: 0,
  });
});
```

Comment: Even if you are stressed by a problem certain words should be reserved for a less public audience.

Comment: This code must be put in a plugin file, for instance `plugins/index.ts` see : https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/plugins/

Comment: I got "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later." So I just leave a comment here. 
I have to say, this answer is helpful but not precise... It would make confusing... I hope every time someone wants to give the answer please give more details.
First, this code can be created just inside of "/plugins" directory. No need to specify as "index.ts" 
Second, the nuxtApp as a parameter does not need to specify the type again... The callback of defineNuxPlugin does it already.
Third, please git it a return statement.

Your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In your SSR, you must pass an `ID_INJECTION_KEY`. The error is caused by using multiple components that are the same in a page. Therefore, SSR is not able to differentiate between components. (Or, at least, that's what I understood from a Chinese forum.)

```
import { ID_INJECTION_KEY } from 'element-plus'

app.provide(ID_INJECTION_KEY, {
      prefix: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      current: 0,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Element Plus official nuxt starter code example:

https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus-nuxt-starter/blob/main/app.vue#L2-L7

```js
import { ID_INJECTION_KEY } from 'element-plus'
provide(ID_INJECTION_KEY, {
  prefix: 100,
  current: 0,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this way using nuxtjs version 3.0.0-rc.11 and Elemen-ui 2.2.18

```
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import { ID_INJECTION_KEY } from 'element-plus'
import localeEs from 'element-plus/es/locale/lang/es'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.provide(ID_INJECTION_KEY, {
    prefix: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
    current: 0
  })

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(ElementPlus, {
    size: 'small',
    zIndex: 3000,
    locale: localeEs
  })
})
```

or they can also do it in the following way

```
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import { ID_INJECTION_KEY } from 'element-plus'
import localeEs from 'element-plus/es/locale/lang/es'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.provide(ID_INJECTION_KEY, {
    prefix: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
    current: 0
  }).use(ElementPlus, {
    size: 'small',
    zIndex: 3000,
    locale: localeEs
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// [any name for the file].ts I did name it "element-plus.plugin.ts" under the directory "/plugins"

import { ID_INJECTION_KEY } from "element-plus"

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    return nuxtApp.vueApp.provide(ID_INJECTION_KEY, {
        prefix: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        current: 0,
  })
})
```